# My logo is not sharp in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

My logo (which actually only contains my name ) on my wordpress twenty sixteen child theme site is not completely sharp. I have tried everything like higher resolution uploading in jpg, png or svg. Nothing helped.

I didn't use site title instead of a logo because I don't want to use too many different font families since this might slow down my site. And also I think the font family 'skia' I'm using is not very common so that could make even loading worse.

Hope someone can help me on this. Or correct me if my findings are not correct.

Hazy

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the CSS of your theme is resizing the image. Or maybe you have a plug-in that automatically compresses images on upload.

Comment: I dont think it's a plug in. Im using theme twenty sixteen. Do you have any idea how I can  stop the theme compressing it ?

Comment: First you have to find out what really the problem is. Check what plug ins you have installed. And check with your browser web inspector if there is any css being applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

if this is still relevant, i have come across the solution.

1. i had the same issue
2. no matter what logo i made or even text only it had some blurry effect
3. the key to this is when you export your logo (in Photoshop for ex), set the height and width to the desired size, and set the same height and width in the Wordpress customizer as well.
4. in my case i have made my logo in PNG at the size of 500x200 and exported it to 200x80PX
5. in Wordpress im using OceanWp as a theme, this allows you to set the height and width of your logo inside the settings of the customizer.
6. so basically set it to 200x80 and your good to go
7. my logo contains only text and a square
8. my logo now looks sharp as the sky :)

[image]